# Show particular Block on the particular URL/page only

Tags: magento2, php-7, luma-theme

I am newcomer in Magento development, after 2 weeks I still feeling lost in the Magento 2 world.

I have added following Block to the app/design/frontend/Mojambe/LuarBiasa/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml:

```
    <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <block class="Mojambe\Blog\Block\Html\MainImage" name="page.main.title" template="Mojambe_Blog::html/mainimage.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

[image]

My proble is the block keep showing on all the pages when I only want it to show on the Home page only.

How to make a particular block only show on the particular page/url in magento 2.3 ?

**I have tried this as well but still no luck:**

[image]

[image]

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the Answer, to add a Block to particular page (in my case home page) just add following line in the page content:

```
<p>{{block class="Mojambe\Blog\Block\Html\MainImage" template="Mojambe_Blog::html/mainimage.phtml"}}</p>
```

Please don't confuse with widget, block use **class** instead off **type** in the property.

[image]

First line is Block and second line is Widget.